# Spring Boot: Secured RESTful API using Spring Social and Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-social, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to define and secure a RESTful API using Spring Boot. Ideally, I would like to use Spring Social and allow clients (web and mobile) to login via Facebook.

**What is working**

So far, I managed to have a working API using `@RestController` and secure it with a basic Spring Security configuration as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and().httpBasic()
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

The `antMatchers` could probably be improved, but I made it like this for my own clarity for now and it works fine. Doing GET requests is allowed and all others required to send the standard `user:password` given by Spring Security at runtime. An example using `httpie`:

```
http POST user:a70fd629-1e29-475d-aa47-6861feb6900f@localhost:8080/api/ideas/ title="My first idea"
```

Which right credentials, it sends a `200 OK` back, otherwise a `401 Unauthorized`.

**Spring Social**

Now, I am stuck and can't get my head around using `Spring-Social-Facebook` to get working with my current setup and keep fully RESTful controllers. Using standard forms and redirects seems trivial, but I couldn't find any solution for a REST-based approach that easily supports web and mobile clients for example.

As I understand, the client will have to handle the flow, since the back-end won't send any redirects to the `/connect/facebook` URL.

- I followed the tutorial [Accessing Facebook Data](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/) and it works on its own. However, I would like to avoid having to have those `facebookConnect.html` and `facebookConnected.html` templates like in the tutorial. So I don't know how to have change that.
- Another [Spring Boot tutorial for OAuth](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_authserver) is also nice and working, but I would like to stick with `Spring Social` if possible due to the simplicity.
- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966027/automatic-configuration-of-spring-social-s-connectcontroller-not-working), helped for the `Method not allowed` issue of the `/connect/facebook` redirect when using those views mentioned above.
- Post about [Social Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712084/facebook-login-with-spring-social-using-existing-user-access-token). Probably, I am missing something there.

Any advice, solution or link to a better tutorial would be really helpful.

**Thanks!**

**UPDATE 1**

Now, I have a working website with traditional User SignUp and Login over forms. I have a "Login with Facebook" button that sends me over the "OAuth dance". So next issue is that I have to create somehow the User manually after the Facebook login has been successful, because for the moment both "logins" are not related, so even though the user is logged in with Facebook, he doesn't yet have an associated User object with the right authorisations.

Comment: Hi ralph, can you share how you did it at the end .. a rest api with ability to signup/signin for both web and mobile apps using both social and normal form registration .. that's exactly what I need and I'm stuck with the same problem you were stuck in

Comment: Did you ever get a satisfactory solution to this? I have exactly the same requirement in that I want my REST api secured by a facebook login, and I'm having trouble understanding how the oauth dance works in this context without having controllers with views ( eg `facebookConnect.html`) in my RESTful api

Comment: Did anyone managed to get the final solution, all the information is so scattered, im sure many people have this problem when it comes to implementing this on mobile apps

Comment: I have the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222417/how-to-sign-up-new-user-via-spring-social-facebook) in case you can provide an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

`SocialAuthenticationFilter` by default, redirects to `'/signup'` in the case you described, user is signed in from a social app, however, no local account exists. You can provide a handler to create a local account. This is also covered in the `spring-socal` samples.

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/signup" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newRegistrationSocial(WebRequest request, Model model) throws Exception {
    String view = "redirect:/home";
    try {
        Connection<?> connection = providerSignInUtils.getConnectionFromSession(request);
        if (connection != null) {
            UserProfile up = connection.fetchUserProfile();

            registerUser(up.getFirstName(), up.getLastName(), up.getEmail(), "DummyPassword");              
            providerSignInUtils.doPostSignUp(up.getEmail(), request);

            //SignInUtils.signin(up.getEmail());
            ...
            ...             
        } 
    } 
    return view;
}
```

Comment: What I do not get ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222417/how-to-sign-up-new-user-via-spring-social-facebook)) is how to correctly redirect the web client. I cannot return something like `redirect:/home` because the web client is separate from the rest api.